# Whats wrong in this SQLite select statement?

Tags: select, sqlite, group-by

I have two table:

Table1 is:

```
ID    fname    lname
---------------------
11      p1        p2
22      a1        a2
```

Table2 is:

```
ID  fk_id    field1    field2
------------------------------
1     11        2        3
2     22        5        4
```

and I have this statement in sqlite:

```
select * from Table1
where Table1.id=(select fk_id
                 from Table2
                 where (select sum([field1]-[field2]) 
                        from Table2 GROUP BY [fk_id]) > 0)
```

I expect that this query return all rows of Table1 but it return just one row!

why?!

I can't understand this!

Comment: `where Table1.id=(..)` is a singular match. Use a JOIN instead of a subquery (or `IN` if one really likes subqueries).

Comment: The problem is that this statement does not make sense. What do you actually want?

Comment: tnx alot! :) user2864740 ;)  I used IN and it worked well !

Answer (score 0):

It would help if there was the result.

So I guess because for table 11
sum(2 - 3) = -1
which fails for

```
select fk_id
                 from Table2
                 where (select sum([field1]-[field2]) 
                        from Table2 GROUP BY [fk_id]) > 0
```

So you only got 22 as your result.

You probably need a abs(sum([field1]-[field2]) then.